# How to left-align the text in a Bootstrap accordion

Tags: html, css

I'm building a static website based on the [W3schools "Company" theme](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp). The full code for the website (including CSS) is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
  <title>Peek Solutions</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.8;
      color: #818181;
  }
  h2 {
      font-size: 24px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #303030;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  h4 {
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #303030;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
  }  
  .jumbotron {
        background-image: url("img/shutterstock_339692003.jpg");
      /*background-color: #85c1e9;*/
      color: #fff;
      padding: 100px 25px;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .container-fluid {
      padding: 60px 50px;
  }
  .bg-grey {
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
  }
  .logo-small {
      color: #85c1e9;
      font-size: 50px;
  }
  .logo {
      color: #85c1e9;
      font-size: 200px;
  }
  .thumbnail {
      padding: 0 0 15px 0;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;
  }
  .thumbnail img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
      background-image: none;
      color: #85c1e9;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {
      border-color: #85c1e9;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li.active {
      background-color: #85c1e9;
  }
  .item h4 {
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: italic;
      margin: 70px 0;
  }
  .item span {
      font-style: normal;
  }
  .panel {
      border: 1px solid #85c1e9; 
      border-radius:0 !important;
      transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  }
  .panel:hover {
      box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
  }
  .panel-footer .btn:hover {
      border: 1px solid #85c1e9;
      background-color: #fff !important;
      color: #85c1e9;
  }
  .panel-heading {
      color: #fff !important;
      background-color: #85c1e9 !important;
      padding: 25px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
      border-top-left-radius: 0px;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  .panel-footer {
      background-color: white !important;
  }
  .panel-footer h3 {
      font-size: 32px;
  }
  .panel-footer h4 {
      color: #aaa;
      font-size: 14px;
  }
  .panel-footer .btn {
      margin: 15px 0;
      background-color: #85c1e9;
      color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      /*background-color: #818181;*/
      z-index: 9999;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 12px !important;
      line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      border-radius: 0;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
      color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
      color: #85c1e9 !important;
      background-color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;
  }
  footer .glyphicon {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      color: #85c1e9;
  }
  .slideanim {visibility:hidden;}
  .slide {
      animation-name: slide;
      -webkit-animation-name: slide;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      visibility: visible;
  }
  @keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-4 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
    .btn-lg {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .logo {
        font-size: 150px;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

<!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Welcome to Peek Solutions</h1> 
  <p>Pipeline integrity solutions and assurance support for the energy industry.</p> 
  <!-- <form class="form-inline">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
  </form> -->
</div>

<!-- Container (About Section) -->
<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2>About us</h2><br>
      <h4>Peek Solutions, an independent consulting company founded by Ralf Peek, provides pipeline integrity solutions and assurance support for the energy industry including application of structural reliability methods to assess and ensure integrity.</h4><br>
      <p>Peek Consulting is a consulting company founded by Ralf Peek.</p>
      <br><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Get in Touch</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal logo"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Container (Services Section) -->
<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
  <h2>SERVICES</h2>
  <h4>Our services include:</h4>
  <br>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Pipeline Integrity Assessment and Design</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Includes design/assessment of subea pipelines for lateral and/or upheaval buckling,  arctic pipelines subject to ice gouging, stamukha loadings and/or thaw settlements, pipelines crossing active faults, as well as well as more routine design/assessment.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Structural Reliability Assessment (SRA)</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Ralf Peek has over 30 years of experience in the area of structural reliability assessment, the estimation and assessment of uncertainties affecting structural performance in order to ensure that safety margins are adequate to cover such uncertainties, including:
        <ul>
            <li>Reliability-based design of buried arctic subsea pipeline against loading by ice keels gouging the sea floor.</li>
            <li>SRA for pipelines subject to lateral buckling under thermal expansion.</li>
            <li>Operating pipelines subject to extreme conditions (for example, turbidity current loading).</li>
            <li>Probabilistic response-based seismic loading assessment criteria.</li>
            <li>Nuclear containment structure reliability assessment.</li>
        </ul>
        </p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
        Collapsible Group 3</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



</div>

<!-- Container (Contact Section) -->
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p>Contact us and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Chicago, US</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> +00 1515151515</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> myemail@something.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>

<!-- Add Google Maps -->
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.878114, -87.629798);

function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:12,
  scrollwheel:false,
  draggable:false,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <a href="#myPage" title="To Top">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
  </a>
  <!-- <p>Bootstrap Theme Made By <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" title="Visit w3schools">www.w3schools.com</a></p> -->
</footer>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 900, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".slideanim").each(function(){
      var pos = $(this).offset().top;

      var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos < winTop + 600) {
          $(this).addClass("slide");
        }
    });
  });
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

One problem I'm having is with the text alignment in the accordion in the "Services" section. It is currently aligned to the center as shown below:

[image]

However, this looks funny for bulleted lists, and I'd like to align it to the left. However, I don't see what's causing it to align to the center, as the `panel` CSS classes don't have a `text-align` attribute as far as I can tell. How can I modify the code to left-align the text in the accordion?

Comment: `#accordion { text-align: left }` ?

Comment: @mahatmanich Of course it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/njpqf469/

Comment: You are right it will work! It would be better however to use built in bootstrap classes to achive this, cause they are already there ... `class="text-left"` on accordion does the job with ease ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Turnip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746736/turnip)'s comment, I added the following line to the CSS code (within the `<style>` tags):

```
#accordion {text-align: left};
```

This has the desired effect of left-aligning the text in the accordion while leaving the rest centered:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The text-center on the `<div id="services" ...` does the initial text alignment of all elements.

To overwrite this behavior try to add the class `text-left` in the html you posted on the `<div id="accordion" ...` element. **That is the bootstrap way to do it!**

Your code:

```
<!-- Container (Services Section) -->
<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
  <h2>SERVICES</h2>
  <h4>Our services include:</h4>
  <br>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Pipeline Integrity Assessment and Design</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
```

Should be:

```
<!-- Container (Services Section) -->
<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
  <h2>SERVICES</h2>
  <h4>Our services include:</h4>
  <br>

  <div class="panel-group text-left" id="accordion"> <!-- add class text-left here -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Pipeline Integrity Assessment and Design</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the class causing the center
[image: this is the class causing the center]

here is why
[image]

and here how you can discover it in chrome
[image]

Answer (score -1):

try

```
.panel {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: and why i get down vote, isnt it solved problem? any explanation plz